# I can't set breakpoint on MessageQueue.class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, breakpoints

I want to learn how work android program.
So I read cord , watch call hierarchy , set breakpoint and trace program.
But now I can't set breakpoint on MessageQueue.class which is default class.

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        dispose();
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}

// Disposes of the underlying message queue.
// Must only be called on the looper thread or the finalizer.
private void dispose() {
    if (mPtr != 0) {
        nativeDestroy(mPtr);
        mPtr = 0;
    }
}
```

This is a part of MessageQueue.class.

If I double-clicked left of line of "super.finalize();" , I can set breakpoint.
But if I double-clicked left of line of "nativeDestroy(mPtr);" , I can't set breakpoint.

And I perceived two things about methods which is under finalize().

1) In OutlineView they are not displayed.

2) They can't be collapsed.Because don't be displayed such button.

So I suspect my eclipse can't read under finalize() code as java.
But I can't find what I have to do.

Please help me someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a breakpoint that allows you to go to the nativeDestroy method you can set a breakpoint on the if test. Then you would have to step into or step over to get passes the if test.

Comment: I’m very sorry. I think I’m insufficient study about English and programing.
There are two words which I can’t understand.
They are “nativeDestroy method” and “if test”
If you had a time , please tell me.

Comment: The nativeDesroy method is your nativeDestroy(mPtr) line. The if test is the if (mPtr != 0) line.

Comment: Thank you your answer. But unfortunately I can’t set a breakpoint on the if test when I double-clicked.

Comment: When you are clicking for the breakpoints where are you exactly expecting the breakpoint to show up and where were you clicking to add the breakpoint.